# Calculating incremental average using java

Tags: java, arrays, average

I have 2 arrays and I want to calculate incremental average and store it again in an array. I am giving an example.

```
int[] arr1 = {1,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,6};
int[] arr2 = {8,9,2,4,5,7,1,8,3,6};
```

after calculation i want output as

```
int[] arr1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6}
double[] average = {8.5,6.3333,5.75,5.5,5.222,5.3}
```

The average works like this ,
For 1 in arr1 the average is 8+9/2

For 2, average is 8+9+2/3, etc.

I have written a for loop which does that but I want to do some faster calculation as the original data I have is of size 800 and has values as 1400000 and is already sorted. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: If you already have a working solution but want it improved this might be a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If your solution have just one for loop it is not possible to make it better since you have a `o(n)` solution. But if you have nested loops your code could have an improvement

Comment: maybe you want to look here [estimately incremental averaging](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106700/incremental-averageing)

Comment: I have nested loop and that is why the code takes time with such huge data. @Lrrr if you could just suggest how to do it. i will be able to code it

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ no its not an integer. Consider it to be a different array altogether. I will edit my question

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of recursion in order to avoid recalculating the incremental sum :

```
Avg(a,b,c) = (a + b + c) / 3

Avg(a,b,c,d) = (a + b + c + d) / 4
             = (a + b + c) / 4 + d/4
             = ((a + b + c) / 3) * 4/3 + d/4
             = Avg(a,b,c) * 4/3 + d/4

=> Avg (x1->xn+1) = Avg(x1->xn) * (n+1)/n + xn+1/(n+1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [DP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). If you are using nested loops it probably means that you are calculating the average for each element in a loop. For making your code to run faster you can just use one loop like this:

```
int[] input = {1,1,2,3,4,4,4,4,5,6};
double[]average = new double[input.length];
double ave = 0;
for(int i = 0 ; i< input.length ; i++)
{
    ave = (input[i] + ave * i)/(i+1);
    average[i] = ave;
}
```

**PS** : your answers are wrong correct answers are :

```
{1.0 , 1.0 , 1.3333333333333333 , 1.75 , 2.2 , 2.5 , 2.7142857142857144 , 2.875 , 3.111111111111111 , 3.4}
```

and

```
{8.0 , 8.5 , 6.333333333333333 , 5.75 , 5.6 , 5.833333333333333 , 5.142857142857143 , 5.5 , 5.222222222222222 , 5.3}
```

Comment: No. No. I might have made a mistake in explaining. Its a misunderstanding. The average is calculated for `arr2` and not `arr1`. Second point, the entries in `arr1` are duplicate. Like I have 2 values as 1, so after my calculation I want unique values. And average calculation goes like this , 


for 1, (8+9)/2

for 2, (8+9+2)/3
for 3, (8+9+2+4)/4
for 4, (8+9+2+4+5+7+1+8)/8

Comment: @Riddhi I still cant understand your problem, please explain how you have `6` elements in `average` instead of `9`? Please explain each element in `average` and what is the purpose of `arr1` ?